# Как внутри гема узнать какое приложение его сейчас использует?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, gems

Существует система, включает в себя некоторое количество приложений, которые общаются друг с другом по REST. Допустим два приложения используют один гем. В одно из них посылаем REST запрос, который провоцирует работу гема, так как мы вызываем роут, описанный гемом. Как изящнее всего опознать гемом приложение, к которому мы обращаемся?

Comment: Опознать приложение **по какому признаку**? Названию главного класса? Урлу? Чему-то ещё?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри контроллеров доступен хелпер `main_app`.
Через этот хелпер есть возможность обращаться к хелперам основного приложения из `Engine`(я так понял, что ваш гем - встроенное приложение, `Engine`).

Для каждого приложения, можно определить уникальный ключ, вынести его в конфиг, и написать хелпер, который его возвращает.
И к этому хелперу обращаться из вашего `Engine`, например так: `main_app.helper_with_app_key`

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто добавить возможность конфигурирования в гем.
В гайдах, например, [используют](http://rusrails.ru/engines#konfigurirovanie-engine) `mattr_accessor`.